# How can I extract specific columns with header names from an HTML file using Perl's HTML::TableExtract

Tags: html, perl

I would like to extract information from the following html block to extract specific columns with header in Perl using [HTML::TableExtract](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML::TableExtract).

```
<tr>
<th>Lane</th>
<th>Sample ID</th>
<th>Sample Ref</th>
<th>Index</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Control</th>
<th>Project</th>
<th>Yield (Mbases)</th>
<th>% PF</th>
<th># Reads</th>
<th>% of raw clusters per lane</th>
<th>% Perfect Index Reads</th>
<th>% One Mismatch Reads (Index)</th>
<th>% of &gt;= Q30 Bases (PF)</th>
<th>Mean Quality Score (PF)</th>
</tr>
</table></div>
<div ID="ScrollableTableBodyDiv"><table width="100%">
<col width="4%">
<col width="5%">
<col width="19%">
<col width="8%">
<col width="7%">
<col width="5%">
<col width="12%">
<col width="7%">
<col width="4%">
<col width="5%">
<col width="4%">
<col width="5%">
<col width="6%">
<col width="5%">
<col>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>test3_5_1</td>
<td></td>
<td>NoIndex</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td>ABC</td>
<td>20,091</td>
<td>100.00</td>
<td>200,905,366</td>
<td>100.00</td>
<td>0.00</td>
<td>0.00</td>
<td>87.39</td>
<td>34.75</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>test5_1</td>
<td></td>
<td>NoIndex</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td>ABC</td>
<td>10,280</td>
<td>100.00</td>
<td>102,799,692</td>
<td>100.00</td>
<td>0.00</td>
<td>0.00</td>
<td>89.60</td>
<td>35.57</td>
</tr>
```

such that I can have output as

```
    Lane    Sample ID   Sample Ref  Index   Description Control  Yield (Mbases) % of &gt;= Q30 Bases (PF)
1   test3_5_1       NoIndex         20,091  87.39
2   test5_1     NoIndex         10,280  89.6
```

Columns 'Sample Ref', 'Description', 'Control' will be empty but have to be printed.

I have tried something like this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use HTML::TableExtract;

my @header=("Lane", "Sample ID", "Sample Ref", "Index", "Description", "Control", " Yield (Mbases)", " % of &gt;= Q30 Bases (PF)");

my $te= new HTML::TableExtract (depth=>0, count=>1, headers=> \@header );
$te->parse_file('testhtml.txt');
my $table = $te->first_table_found;

   foreach my $table ( $te->tables ) {
        foreach  my $row ($table->rows) {
        no warnings "uninitialized";
        print "   ", join("\t", @$row), "\n";
       }
    }
```

I am not able to get desired output. Please help improve my code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

More than likely, the culprit is

> #### headers
>
> Passed as an array reference, headers specify strings of interest at the top of columns within targeted tables. ***They can be either strings or regular expressions (qr//). If they are strings, they will eventually be passed through a non-anchored, case-insensitive regular expression, so regexp special characters are allowed.*** (emphasis mine)

One option is to use distinct substrings corresponding to each column you want to extract. Another is to pass each string through [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html). Finally, you can just use patterns as in `qr/\QYield (Mbases)/` or `qr/\Q% of >= Q30 Bases (PF)/`. I find using distinct substrings to be more convenient. After all, sometimes people do change column headers, but there is usually some distinct substring that must be present regardless of presentation.

Since you did not give a sample table body in your example, I used the `keep_headers` option to be able to show some output. It is also useful in providing you with the actual headers that were used.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use HTML::TableExtract;

my $te = HTML::TableExtract->new(
    headers => [
        'Lane',
        'ID',
        'Ref',
        'Index',
        'Description',
        'Control',
        'Yield',
        'Q30 Bases',
    ],
    keep_headers => 1,
);

$te->parse_file(\*DATA);
my @rows = $te->first_table_found->rows;

for my $row (@rows) {
    print join("\n", map qq{'$_'}, @$row), "\n";
}

__DATA__
<div><table><tr>
<th>Lane</th>
<th>Sample ID</th>
<th>Sample Ref</th>
<th>Index</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Control</th>
<th>Project</th>
<th>Yield (Mbases)</th>
<th>% PF</th>
<th># Reads</th>
<th>% of raw clusters per lane</th>
<th>% Perfect Index Reads</th>
<th>% One Mismatch Reads (Index)</th>
<th>% of &gt;= Q30 Bases (PF)</th>
<th>Mean Quality Score (PF)</th>
</tr>
</table></div>
```

Output:

```
$ ./jj.pl
'Lane'
'Sample ID'
'Sample Ref'
'Index'
'Description'
'Control'
'Yield (Mbases)'
'% of >= Q30 Bases (PF)'
```